# Web2py display "None", and I want to display nothing

Tags: web2py

If I got an empty value from my database, web2py display "None" and I would like to display just a blank space (or nothing).
Note: I do not need to change anything on the database value, just on the resulting display.

I am using SQLFORM.smartgrid and getting the following:

- column1: 35.75
- column2: None
- column3: 12.65

I would like to display:

- column1: 35.75
- column2:
- column3: 12.65

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance for your help.
Jose.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the "represent" attribute of the field, either at table definition time:

```
db.define_table('mytable',
    Field('myfield', represent=lambda v, r: '' if v is None else v))
```

or later:

```
db.mytable.myfield.represent = lambda v, r: '' if v is None else v
```

Comment: I have used it before my SQLFORM.smartgrid and worked perfectly, and it does not change the field values, just what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

sample

{{= request.vars.var }} show None

{{= request.vars.var or ''}} resolv

Answer (score 0):

Anthony's answer works fine for normal fields. But if your field happens to be a reference field, you would want to do this to utilize the source table's `_format` setting:

```py
db.define_table("thing",
    Field("owner_id", db.person,
        represent=lambda value, row:
            "" if value is None
            else db.person._format % value,  # Here we assume db.person._format
                                             # is a string rather than a lambda, though
        ),
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For a reference field a sample solution is:

```
...
Field('licenciador_fk', 'reference entidade', represent=lambda v, r: '-' if v is None else v.name)
```

where `name` is the field format of entidade table

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).